# How to convert string to rapid json value

Tags: c++11, rapidjson

I am using rapidjson library to encode and deconde the json.

I have received the string lets say  string Str = "msisdn-123456789"; 
i want to covert this into a rapidjson value but it says parsing error. and value type is still kNullType

I am using below code snippest.

```
std::string Str = "msisdn-123456789";
rapidjson::Document newDoc;
newDoc.Parse(Str.c_str());
rapidjson::Value value(rapidjson::kNullType);
value.CopyFrom(newDoc, newDoc.GetAllocator());
cout << "Type of value" << static_cast<uint32_t>(value.GetType()) << endl;
```

The output is kNullType (0) .

How can i convert string to rapidjson value ?

Answer (score 0):

`std::string Str = "msisdn-123456789";` is not a valid JSON. So parsing it will have an null value at the document root.
For constructing a `Value` by `std::string s`, just

```
Value v(s, allocator);                   // When RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING=1
Value v(s.c_str(), s.size(), allocator); // Otherwise
```